# how to bring video.js playbutton to front of canvas that is in front of video element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video.js

I am using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com) to make a frontpage and i am letting these [birds](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html) fly around freely in front of the video player, so i set the div that contains the video element to a very negative z-index, but however, then i can't press play because the play button is set behind the birds (canvas) too because it's a child of the video.
[image]
How can i get the play button in front of the birds at the beginning so that i can press play (i will move the container back in front of them onclick)?

code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function bringPlayButtonInFrontOfBirds(){
     document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-big-play-button")[0].style.zIndex = "200000";
     document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-control-bar")[0].style.zIndex = "200000";

    }
</script>
</head>
    <body onload ="bringPlayButtonInFrontOfBirds()">
    <script>//birdcode
    </script>

    <div id="container" style ="position:absolute; left:28%;top:25%; z-index:-1000;">

      <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
           style ="z-index:1000;"
        data-setup='{"techOrder":["youtube","html5"],"ytcontrols":false}'>
        <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1As9ObURDA" type="video/youtube" />
      </video>

   </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can trigger the video play event on click of your flying birds overlay.

```
myPlayer.play();
```

Comment: it's indeed the answer...is it because I haven't written any code?...her you go...answer updated.

Comment: it sounds like a great answer. 
I'm just trying to workout how to set the overlay onclick.
Im pretty new to html5/canvas/three.js.

Comment: got it. i triggered the button's onclick directly, which in turn triggers the player to play like your code.
thanks, this is an elegant solution. dont get so rushy tho ;)

Comment: hey some other guy had commented that its more like a comment than an answer...it wasn't directed to you @jsky :)